# rapidly changing ip address

Tags: networking, internet, ip, dhcp

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this.

I noticed this when I was doing some development in php. I used the remote ip address as one method to track a session of a user.

In some of my testing, I noticed that my ip address was different on every page. Literally seconds between pages, multiple times in a row, my ip address would be different.

Mobile phone on mobile network. Not traveling during testing. I supposed I could be at the edge of multiple towers.

I understand that dhcp causes ip addresses to change and thus be non-static. However, I was under the impression that they should not be changing that quickly.

Is this normal or something I should definitely be concerned with?

Comment: Imagine a user in a car or train or something. They will be changing IP addresses faster than you can imagine (using multiple IP addresses during loading is normal). This is a reason why IP addresses shouldn't be used for identifying users (plus the fact of shared IP addresses).

Comment: "*I used the remote ip address as one method to track a session of a user.*" Why? That's associated with the computer handling the HTTP query and may not have much to do with the user at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most mobile operators use carrier grade NAT to reduce the number of IP's they need, as well as to protect the users on the network. Your phone's data connection will have an 'internal' IP address, and the operator balances all outgoing connections over a pool of IP's.

This is very common and nothing to concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

That right there is what's known as DHCP (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol) where you are assigned your private IP (it probably begins with a 10). This private cannot communicate with the internet and is only internally routable.

In order to communicate with the outside world you needs, what's known as a public IP. With IPv4 we have a limited amount of public IPs (which are unique) therefore we use multiple private IPs to communicate with a one of a small pool of public IPs.

This process is done through NAT (Network Address Translation) which translates your private IP into a public one. NAT is much more intricate and deeper than what I have explained to you here but if you want to read more you can start off [here](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=1725268), an article about NAT by CiscoPress.